# Catch All Record in a Join expression

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, left-join

I have a very simple ( I think it's simple, but I'm still struggling!) problem.  I've got a table of cars.  I've got another table of classes of cars.  I want to join one to the other to get the class for the car.

The cars table is simple with a model and a make.  The class table also has a model and a make and a type of class.  The problem arises when I want to group cars of the same make together regardless of their model.

So for example, I have two vehicles:

```
id  vehiclemake vehiclemodel
1   AUDI            R8
2   AUDI            Quattro
```

And I have two classes:

```
id  vehiclemake vehiclemodel    classtype
1   AUDI            R8          A
2   AUDI            NULL        B
```

The AUDI R8 will match to class type A.  I want all other AUDI's regardless of their model to match to class type B.

I've got some sample code here so you can have a play!

```
create table #vehicle(id int, vehiclemake varchar(10), vehiclemodel varchar(10))
create table #vehicleclass(id int, vehiclemake varchar(10), vehiclemodel varchar(10), classtype varchar(1))


insert into #vehicle values(1, 'AUDI', 'R8')
insert into #vehicle values(2, 'AUDI', 'Quattro')

insert into #vehicleclass values(1, 'AUDI', 'R8', 'A')
insert into #vehicleclass values(2, 'AUDI', null, 'B')


select 
*
from
#vehicle v
left join #vehicleclass vc on 
(v.vehiclemake = vc.vehiclemake and v.vehiclemodel = vc.vehiclemodel)


drop table #vehicle
drop table #vehicleclass
```

The statement above doesn't join the Quattro record to the B class record

Comment: What you want to get output in this case?

Comment: SQLFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf58e/1/0

Comment: In this instance, the result should be:                                                                                                               1 AUDI R8 1 AUDI R8 A
2 AUDI Quattro 2 AUDI NULL B

Comment: Is there a maximum of 1 record per vehiclemake in the table vehicleclass where the vehicle model is null?

Comment: Yes, only one record per model/vehicle make with the model/null being the catch all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is what you want:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #vehicle v
        JOIN #vehicleclass vc ON v.vehiclemake = vc.vehiclemake
                                 AND ( v.vehiclemodel = vc.vehiclemodel
                                       OR ( vc.vehiclemodel IS NULL
                                            AND v.vehiclemodel NOT IN (
                                            SELECT  vehiclemodel
                                            FROM    #vehicleclass
                                            WHERE   vehiclemodel IS NOT NULL )
                                          )
                                     )
```

Output:

```
id  vehiclemake vehiclemodel    id  vehiclemake vehiclemodel    classtype
1   AUDI        R8              1   AUDI        R8              A
2   AUDI        Quattro         2   AUDI        NULL            B
```

Comment: Hello!  I think we may have a winner!

Answer (score 2):

Use a [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) on the join of `vehiclemodel` so that when the model is NULL on the `vehicleclass` table, the vehicle will instead match on its own model.

**[EDIT]**: After reading the user's comment, try this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM #vehicle v
        INNER JOIN #vehicleclass vc 
            ON v.vehiclemake = vc.vehiclemake 
                AND v.vehiclemodel = vc.vehiclemodel
UNION
SELECT *
    FROM #vehicle v
        INNER JOIN #vehicleclass vc 
            ON v.vehiclemake = vc.vehiclemake 
                AND vc.vehiclemodel IS NULL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                         FROM #vehicleclass vc2
                         where vc2.vehiclemake = v.vehiclemake
                            and vc2.vehiclemodel = v.vehiclemodel);
```

Comment: But it's bringing back two records for the R8, where it matches the model and where the model is null.  For the R8 record it should only bring it back once

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM #vehicle v
LEFT JOIN #vehicleclass vc 
ON (v.vehiclemake = vc.vehiclemake 
AND v.vehiclemodel = COALESCE(vc.vehiclemodel, v.vehiclemodel))
WHERE v.Id = vc.id
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  vehiclemake vehiclemodel    id  vehiclemake vehiclemodel    classtype
1       AUDI        R8          1       AUDI        R8              A
2       AUDI      Quattro       2       AUDI        NULL            B
```

Comment: It's just a coincidence that those `Id` values match between the tables. That is not a valid column to match on.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use `UNION ALL` here, since you really have two requirements.

1. Get the class of all vehicles with a matching record in vehicle .
2. Get the default class for all vehicle models with no matching class.

Trying to do this in a single query is possible, but more often than not obscures the execution plan so indexes are not used in an optimal way.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #Vehicle AS v
        INNER JOIN #vehicleclass AS vc
            ON vc.VehicleMake = v.VehicleMake
            AND vc.VehicleModel = v.VehicleModel
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    #Vehicle AS v
        INNER JOIN #vehicleclass AS vc
            ON vc.VehicleMake = v.VehicleMake
            AND vc.VehicleModel IS NULL
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    #vehicleclass AS vc2
            WHERE   vc2.VehicleMake = v.VehicleMake
            AND     vc2.VehicleModel = v.VehicleModel
        );
```

To do this with no union you could use:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #Vehicle AS v
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 *
            FROM    #vehicleclass AS vc
            WHERE   vc.VehicleMake = v.VehicleMake
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN vc.VehicleModel = v.VehicleModel THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        ) AS vc;
```

It will depend on the indexes you have on each table as to which will perform better. With no indexes the latter has a better exection plan, as it simply requires two scans, but if I add indexes to each table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX #IX_Vehicle__VehicleMake_VehicleClass ON #Vehicle (VehicleMake, VehicleModel) ;
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX #IX_VehicleClass__VehicleMake_VehicleClass ON #Vehicle (VehicleMake, VehicleModel);
```

Then the former becomes more efficient as it is able to leverage index seeks better.